# Add item to a TableView that the user sorted by a certain column while respecting the sort

Tags: java, kotlin, javafx, tableview

I have a `TableView` that the user can sort by any of its columns. Depending on other events in the app, I want to add data to the `TableView`. However, when I add the data, the new row always appears on the bottom of the `TableView`, even though it should appear somewhere else according to the sort order.

My question is, therefore, how I can add data to the `TableView` such that the `TableView` is still sorted correctly according to the column that was selected by the user.

Here's the relevant code controlling the `TableView`:

```kotlin
@FXML
private lateinit var tableColumnMeasurementLogBib: TableColumn<LogEntry, Int>

@FXML
private lateinit var tableColumnMeasurementLogResult: TableColumn<LogEntry, Double>

@FXML
private lateinit var tableColumnMeasurementLogTimestamp: TableColumn<LogEntry, LocalDateTime>

@FXML
private lateinit var tableViewMeasurementLog: TableView<LogEntry>

private val logEntries = FXCollections.observableArrayList<LogEntry>()

private fun setupMeasurementLog() {
    tableViewMeasurementLog.items = logEntries
    
    tableColumnMeasurementLogTimestamp.cellValueFactory = PropertyValueFactory(LogEntry::timestamp.name)
    tableColumnMeasurementLogResult.cellValueFactory = PropertyValueFactory(LogEntry::result.name)
    tableColumnMeasurementLogBib.cellValueFactory = PropertyValueFactory(LogEntry::athleteId.name)

    tableColumnMeasurementLogTimestamp.setCellFactory {
        object : TableCell<LogEntry, LocalDateTime>() {
            override fun updateItem(item: LocalDateTime?, empty: Boolean) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty)
                if (empty || item == null) {
                    text = ""
                    return
                }

                text = measurementLogDateTimeFormatter.format(item)
            }
        }
    }
}

private fun addDataToLog(athleteId: Int, result: Double, timestamp: LocalDateTime) {
    logEntries.add(LogEntry(athleteId, result, timestamp))
}

data class LogEntry(val athleteId: Int, val result: Double, val timestamp: LocalDateTime)
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Call `addDataToLog` with some values.
2. In the UI, click on any of the column headers to sort the table by that column.
3. Call `addDataToLog` again.
4. The new data row will always appear at the bottom, no matter where it should actually appear (according to the sorted column).

Answer (score 3):

Turns out reading the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html) would have been of great help here. Simply wrapping the list in a `SortedList` like so does the job:

```kotlin
val sortedLogs = SortedList(logEntries)
tableViewMeasurementLog.items = sortedLogs
sortedLogs.comparatorProperty().bind(tableViewMeasurementLog.comparatorProperty())
```